# Post Request With Encoded String

Tags: c#, post, request, base64, binary-data

I am working on a website which you can enter a company name and it gives you the address of that company. This website sends request parameters like this:

> params=VTJGc2RHVmtYMThDbWJ2RVZkaEVQZU9MZCtKaU5sNElyTHdiNDY2QlBDNjBXY1ZmdjlsNDQ5UGlQeEw3bGVnQ1dqVGtQbzI0UkZYR3hEUFFrcFcza2JDNXZMdFRVYllsRHliTkVDcEhKMWhTQ3luMHc1K1J1ejdDWkJsbnB6amE=

And request for another company is like this:

> params=VTJGc2RHVmtYMSsrSzZ6cmMzTTJLSkMzK1ppcUt2N05yb0d6TG9YOVZEa3ZONzJJcWkzbmlsemRMZVhhRXlvblpaVEY4bFlBbmQrdGpuWnR4NllSdWVBUFN0dHhRSXZsZHF4TmdHRzlJVnJTUTRXRjFLeDZCUmJadGdGWWl6UEw=

I know this site sending requests as Json format but I cannot deserialize that request parameters as json string so that I cannot simulate my post request.

And as you can see all requests starts with

> VTJGc2RHVmtYM

tag.

I tried different ways to deserialize that params as json but can't take any results. These params string is not a valid base-64 string or not a binary string as I see.

When I delete the start of that parameter string (VTJGc2RHVmtYM) and convert the rest of the string from base64, I get a value that looks like a binary string but no luck on deserialize that to json too.

So all helps will be appreciated

Comment: Look at the javascript and find how it does the encoding.

Comment: But, to get you started, try base64 decoding it _twice_ and have a read of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124312/decrypting-binary-code-from-a-base64-string .

Comment: Both of those string decode as base 64. The result is a bunch of binary data in each case (which is usuallythe case with base64 data; it's an efficient string representationof binary data). You're going to need more information about what this represents

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I  base64 decoded these strings twice and finally saw that these are  salted encoded data. And after that Salted___ tag, there is some binary data that I couldn't understand or decode. I know that this base64 data represents a json string that is like {"Company Name" : "Company A"}. Is that information worth something to decode that binary data ? And did they use SHA-256 or alike hash to encode that binary data that is after Salted___ tag ? If so I think it is impossible to decode these base64 file. By the way I tried Newtonsoft Bson reader too but noluck with it