# Why base64 encode twice?

Tags: encoding, base64

I've seen a few posts referencing double-encoded base64 strings (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977909/post-request-with-encoded-string) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650847/determine-if-string-is-base64-encoded-twice)). Why is this technique necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not *necessary*, it just happens sometimes. If system A encodes all of the data it gets, because it might be binary, and some of that data happens to come from system B, which already encoded its output as base64, then you get double-encoding. It's like asking "when I buy something online, why do I sometimes get a box inside a box?" Because the shipper puts *everything* into a box, even boxes.

Comment: Awesome analogy with the shipping boxes! Yeah, I couldn't see a good reason for it at all, but thought maybe I'm missing something, and there is no info on this "technique" (for good reasons, lol). Thanks for your answer!